# Package location after catkin_make install

Tags: arduino, roslaunch, catkin-make, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I am working with [my version of the ros_arduino_bridge package](https://github.com/kk6axq/ros_arduino_bridge) and I am having some problems with the install. I forked it from github into my ~/catkin_ws/src folder and then ran `catkin_make install` from ~/catkin_ws/ . When I run roslaunch ros_arduino_python arduino.launch

```
lukas@lukas-Inspiron-N7010:~$ roslaunch ros_arduino_python arduino.launch

... logging to /home/lukas/.ros/log/0853208e-ce73-11e4-8f0d-1c659d0cfa61/roslaunch-lukas-Inspiron-N7010-6050.log

Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.

Press Ctrl-C to interrupt

Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

error loading <rosparam> tag:
        file does not exist [/home/lukas/catkin_ws/src/ros_arduino_bridge/ros_arduino_python/config/my_arduino_params.yaml]
XML is <rosparam command="load" file="$(find ros_arduino_python)/config/my_arduino_params.yaml"/>
The traceback for the exception was written to the log file
```

Now I know from previous testing that the problem is that I haven't specified the full path to the .yaml file. So I need to modify the my_arduino_params.yaml file. Here is my problem: When I roscd to the package there is nothing in the folder except for a CMakeLists.txt and a package.xml file. Now I may just be a noob but could some knowledgable sage enlighten me as to where catkin stores these files?
Thanks,
luketheduke

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/205419/package-location-after-catkin_make-install/) by [luketheduke](https://answers.ros.org/users/20641/luketheduke/) on ROS Answers with karma: 285 on 2015-03-19

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2015-03-20**:
Did you write install rules for your yaml file?

**Comment by [luketheduke](https://answers.ros.org/users/20641/luketheduke/) on 2015-03-20**:
What do you mean by "install rules"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> I forked it from github into my `~/catkin_ws/src` folder and then ran `catkin_make install` from `~/catkin_ws/`.

And then you did `source ~/catkin_ws/install/setup.bash`?

> Now I know from previous testing that the problem is that I haven't specified the full path to the .yaml file.

No, you don't and you shouldn't. If you sourced the correct workspace, the `ros_arduino_python` pkg should be on the `ROS_PACKAGE_PATH`, and `roslaunch` / `rospack` should be able to resolve the `$(find ros_arduino_python)` to the proper location.

> When I roscd to the package there is nothing in the folder except for a CMakeLists.txt and a package.xml file.

That is probably in `~/catkin_ws/install/share/PKG_NAME`?

Also:

> ```
> file does not exist [/home/lukas/catkin_ws/src/ros_arduino_bridge/ros_arduino_python/config/my_arduino_params.yaml]
> ```

Is there actually a `my_arduino_params.yaml` in `/home/lukas/catkin_ws/src/ros_arduino_bridge/ros_arduino_python/config/`?

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2015-03-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [luketheduke](https://answers.ros.org/users/20641/luketheduke/) on 2015-03-20**:
My bad I was roscding into the wrong package ros_arduino_bridge instead of ros_arduino_python. Thanks for your help!